# changing the background color on clicking on the button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm learning javascript!

What I need to do, is to change the background-color at the same time when the image is changing by clicking on the button.

Changing the picture, from light-On to light-off, is working properly, the only problem is that the color of the background of my html page, is not changing.

```js
  function colorize() {
            var element = document.getElementById("azul");
            element.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
            element.style.color = "yellow";
        }
```

```css
    html{
         background:
             grey;
     }
     #azul:focus {
         background: blue;
        
     }
```

```html
    <div id="branca">
        <h1>LOI Lampen aanzetten en uitzetten</h1>
        <button id="azul" onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src = '/img/393533_02.PNG'">Turn on the light</button>
        

        <img id="myImage" src="img/393533_01.PNG" class="mudar">
        <div id="yellow">
            <button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage', '').src='/img/393533_01.PNG'">Turn off the light</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you can use `document.body.backgroundColor = 'white'`

Comment: You are changing the background of the button

Comment: You are not calling the colorize function anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change background of html so what you have to do is...

```
function colorize() {
     var element = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
     element.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
}
```

You were taking button element and changing its color. you have to select html tag as you want to change the background-clor property assigned to it via css.

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution call the colorize function too

```
<html>

<script>
function colorize() {
  var element = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
  element.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  element.style.color = "yellow";
}
</script>

<style>
html{
background:
   grey;
}
#azul:focus {
background: blue;

}
</style>
<div id="branca">
<h1>LOI Lampen aanzetten en uitzetten</h1>
<button id="azul" onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src = '/img/393533_02.PNG';colorize()">Turn on the light</button>


<img id="myImage" src="img/393533_01.PNG" class="mudar">
<div id="yellow">
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage', '').src='/img/393533_01.PNG'">Turn off the light</button>
</div>
</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the background color of the `document`, not `element`, which is your button.

Since you are new to JavaScript, let's get you off of some bad habits that you've already picked up.

**Do not set up event handlers via HTML event attributes** (i.e. `onclick`, `onmouseover`, etc.). This is a 25+ year old technique that we used before we had modern standards and best practices and because it's easy to use, people keep using it. But **[there are a variety of reasons why you should not use this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991)** and instead separate your JavaScript from your HTML. Instead, keep your JavaScript separate and use **[`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)** to hook up your elements to their respective callback functions.

Whenever possible, work with pre-made CSS classes because these are easier to manage and reuse than inline CSS styles (via the `.style` property). You can then easily use the **[`element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)** API to add or remove classes as needed.

See the comments inline below:

```js
// Get references to the elements you'll need to work with
let targetImage = document.getElementById('myImage');
let btnOn = document.getElementById("on");
let btnOff = document.getElementById("off");

// Then, set up your event handlers in JavaScript, not HTML
btnOn.addEventListener("click", changeImage);
btnOff.addEventListener("click", changeImage);

function changeImage(){
  // Set the target's source to the data-source attribute for the clicked button 
  targetImage.src = this.dataset.source; 
  targetImage.alt = this.dataset.alt // Now update the alt attribute
  
  // Change the background color of the page by adding or removing a
  // pre-made class to/from the body based on the button that was clicked
  
  // Since this is a simple if/then scenario, we can use the JavaScript "ternary" operator
  // which works like this:   some condition ? what to do if condition is true : what to do if false
  this.id === "on" ? document.body.classList.add("blue") : document.body.classList.remove("blue"); 
}
```

```css
body { background-color: grey; } /* Style the body, not the HTML */ 
#on:focus { background: blue; color:yellow; }
.blue { background-color:aliceblue; } /* This will be added when on is clicked */


/* Just for this example only */
img { width:100px; }
```

```html
<button id="on" data-source='https://cdn.wccftech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/bulb_PNG1250.png' data-alt="On Image">Turn on the light</button>
<button id="off" data-source='https://www.radioducoeur.com/liten/radioducoeur/light-bulb-png-home-design-ideas-4-lightbulb-498-x-498-liten.jpg' data-alt="Off Image">Turn off the light</button>

<div>
  <!-- <img> elements must have an alt attribute to be valid -->
  <img id="myImage" src="https://www.radioducoeur.com/liten/radioducoeur/light-bulb-png-home-design-ideas-4-lightbulb-498-x-498-liten.jpg" class="mudar" alt="default image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code:

```
<style>
    body {
        background: grey;
    }
</style>

<script>
        function colorize(light) {
            if (light) {
                document.getElementById('myImage').src = '/img/393533_02.PNG';
                document.body.style.background = 'grey';
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('myImage').src = '/img/393533_01.PNG'
                document.body.style.background = 'blue';
            }
        }
    </script>

<body>
    <div id="branca">
        <h1>LOI Lampen aanzetten en uitzetten</h1>
        <button id="azul" onclick="colorize(true)">Turn on the light</button>
        <img id="myImage" src="img/393533_01.PNG" class="mudar"/>
        <div id="yellow">
            <button onclick="colorize(false)">Turn off the light</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now in colorize function you can write as much parameters as you want for two different conditions.